# Vector image on ImageView cut when rotates

Tags: android, image, imageview, android-animation, android-vectordrawable

I'm doing some test on Vector images with support compatibility and I got an issue when I was rotating the image.

I do have a simple rotation animation and when the image overtakes the borders it cuts the image. I  used **clipChildren = false** but it seems not doing anything.

the image attached also contains the code  of the layout.

[image]

any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Are you rotating it around its center? Have you set the pivots for the rotation?

Comment: yes I do rotate around its center

Comment: Could you share you vector drawable? Also are you rotating by using an animated vector drawable or sth else?